# Convert Spark Dataset to JSON and Write to Kafka Producer

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, kafka-producer-api

I want to read a table from Hive and write to Kafka Producer(batch job).

Currently, I am reading the table as `Dataset<Row>` in my java class and trying to convert to a json so that i can write as json message using KafkaProducer.

```
Dataset<Row> data = spark.sql("select * from tablename limit 5");
List<Row> rows = data.collectAsList();
for(Row row: rows) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(row.schema().fieldNames())); 
        Seq<String> row_seq = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(stringList.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
        Map map = (Map) row.getValuesMap(row_seq);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.putAll( map);

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(SPARK_CONF.get("topic.name"), json.toString());
        producer.send(record);
```

I am getting ClassCastException

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code

Comment: Have included the code. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you write `collectAsList();`, you are no longer using Spark, just raw Kafka Java API.

My suggestion would be to use [Spark Structured Streaming Kafka Integration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka) and you can do

Here is an example, and you need to form a DataFrame with at least two columns because Kafka takes keys and values.

```
// Write key-value data from a DataFrame to a specific Kafka topic specified in an option
data.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("topic", "topic_name")
  .save()
```

As far as getting data into JSON, again, `collectToList()` is wrong. Do not pull data into a single node.

You can use `data.map()` to convert a DataSet from one format into another.

For example, you would map a Row into a String that is in JSON format.

```
row -> "{\"f0\":" + row.get(0) + "}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the logic which i have mentioned above can be done in scala.
Here is the code:
val df = spark.sql("select * from table limit 5")
val row = df.first()
val m = row.getValuesMap(row.schema.fieldNames)
JSONObject(m).toString()
I am trying replicate the same logic in java and write it to a Producer.
The difference is just here in scala it is able to convert the scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Nothing] type to JSONObject type directly, whereas in case of Java it gives error.
Please suggest

Comment: You should be able to create a `new JSONObject` from a Java HashMap, but you need to know how to convert a Scala map into a hava map, however, again, `row.first()` would not give you all the dataframe rows as Kafka events.